# How to find object which id is not available in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have 2 Array of objects. In which one is the original array, and another array contains the modified array. The modified array can contain new objects, edited object, or deleted object in `settingValueDtoList`

Currently, I am writing code for a new record in settingValueDtoList. If I am adding some new object in any settingValueDtoList then its id will be like a0, or a1 or a2 like this. I am just iterating both arrays and checking if id is not present in the `original` array, it means it is a new object, I want to push that object into my `addSettingArray` variable.

How can I fetch that new record whose id is not present in the original array?

This is what I tried.

```
compareSetting(settingArray: Array<any>) {
    console.log('abc', this.settingObject)
    console.log('settingArray',settingArray)

    let settingIndex = 0;
    
    this.settingObject.forEach(unmodifiedSetting => {   
      let modifiedSetting = settingArray[settingIndex];

      modifiedSetting.settingValueDtoList.forEach(editedSettingValue => {
          unmodifiedSetting.settingValueDtoList.forEach(uneditedSettingValue => {
            if(editedSettingValue.id != uneditedSettingValue.id) {
              this.addSettingArray.push(editedSettingValue);
            }
          });
      })
      settingIndex++;
    })

    console.log('add', this.addSettingArray)
  }
```

Comment: Usually a good pattern when updating such a thing is to delete and recreate everything, so you don't have to care about the delta. It's not always a viable solution though.

Comment: @LaurentS. is there any improvement I need.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
compareSetting(settingArray: Array<any>) {
console.log('abc', this.settingObject)
console.log('settingArray',settingArray)

let settingIndex = 0;

this.settingObject.forEach(unmodifiedSetting => {   
  let modifiedSetting = settingArray[settingIndex];

  modifiedSetting.settingValueDtoList.forEach(editedSettingValue => {
      let isNewEntry = true;
      unmodifiedSetting.settingValueDtoList.forEach(uneditedSettingValue => {
        if(editedSettingValue.id == uneditedSettingValue.id) {
          isNewEntry = false;
        }
      });
      
      if (isNewEntry){
          this.addSettingArray.push(editedSettingValue);
      }
  })
  settingIndex++;
})

console.log('add', this.addSettingArray)
```

}

Edit:
More abstract for better understanding:

```
array1.forEach(entry1 => 
{
  let isNewEntry = true; // says if entry1 is not present in array2
  array2.forEach(entry2 => 
  {
    if(entry1.id == entry2.id) 
    {
      isNewEntry = false; // the entry1 was found in array2
    }
  });
  
  if (isNewEntry)
  {
      // the entry1 was not found in array2 - do whatever you want here
  }
});
```

Comment: It worked for me. I didn't get what was wrong in my code?

Comment: You are checking all the possible combinations of your ids. But in your example there are only 4 combinations that would return false for your condition "if(editedSettingValue.id != uneditedSettingValue.id)". Any other combination would return true i.e. "144 != 151".
I hope I could explain it to you understandably.

Comment: Hi...I am also doing same thing for deleting. I want to find the id of that object which is not present in the modified array. I want to check all id's. I want to compare original array and modified array, if modified array dont't contain that id which is in original array then that id i want to push in my deleteArray variable. Same problem i am facing again

Comment: Can you add this in answer please

Comment: I updated the answer. It should now be explained better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226099/discussion-between-thetechguy-and-jonathan-distenfeld).